# ${__fifoPop(sync_tokensqo, gotTokenq_2)} empty the stack, what we supposed to do when we need same token for other request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I summarized my code as given below
User Login -100 times 
Jsr233 post-processor put 100 tokens.
While loop 
{counter 
user login-100 times
Jsr 223 preprocessor -pop 100 tokens
}
 On loop count 1, its pops all token, nothing left for count 2. How o handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

1. If Login and While Loop are in the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - use `vars` shorthand for the [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

   ```
   vars.put('gotTokenq_2', 'token_value_here') // store the variable
   ```
2. If Login and While Loop are in different Thread Groups - use `props` shorthand instead:

   to set the value:

   ```
   props.put('token_' + ctx.getThreadNum(), 'token value here')
   ```

   to read the value:

   ```
   vars.put('gotTokenq_2', props.get('token_' + ctx.getThreadNum()))
   ```

In both cases you wil be able to access the token value as `${gotTokenq_2}` where required

More information on these `vars`, `props`, and `ctx` shortcuts: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Comment: If I work on 100 users, I need to add 100 vars.put("',''")? Any alternative please?

Comment: You need to have it only once, each user will have its own token